# iOS : How to call an API runtime when I start typing in UITextfield?

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, uitextfield

Here is the one example :
[image]
**Image 1** - It contain a UITextfield say emailTextField. When I start typing then according to its keyword in background one API will call which will gives response according to your keyword.

API used for searching is like

```
url/collaborator/search
```

and parameters are,

```
1. token 
2. term
```

**Image 2** - When I started typing like "ma", then in backround that api call has to call,
i.e API call be like

```
url/collaborator/search?token=kdkhu67tdndodAK803i939ndAJDEw & term=ma
```

so it will give response, and that response it has to be show like drop down which is shown in image

**Image 3** - If type specific name, then according to its data it has to filter the emails and specific email has to come, and when I click on it it has to add in textfield. I want single search as well as multiple email search.

```
url/collaborator/search?token=kdkhu67tdndodAK803i939ndAJDEw & term=komal
```

Currently I want to implement single at a time, if more than one can able do or add then no issue.

**So, how to call api at run time when I start typing in textfield and get data in array ?????**

Comment: you can call in textfield delegate method shouldChangeCharactersInRange but it take more load whenever you type single keyword. So when you write single keyword or erase then everytime api calls

Comment: can you plz tell me, how to call an API in shouldChangeCharactersInRange method and where I will get response and how to I use that response showing results ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write below code,

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSLog(@"Data is : %@",_ccTextField.text);


    [self collaboratorApiMethod:_ccTextField.text];

    return YES;
}


// This metod is used to add collaborator, it will call API according to enetered data, JSON will receive
-(void)collaboratorApiMethod:(NSString*)valueFromTextField
{
   NSString *url =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/collaborator/search?token=%@&term=%@",[userDefaults objectForKey:@"token"],valueFromTextField];
   // so this will generate in url

   // call api (REST API call)
   // you will get JSON data, store in array/dictionaries
}
```

Assume that, you got an array which contains a list of emails. Now that email you have to show suggestions when a user starts typing in textField and according to its value data will filter and show suggestion.

write below code,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)autoSuggestionField:(UITextField *)field tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forText:(NSString *)text {

  userSearchDataCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"userSearchDataCellId"];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"userSearchDataCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSArray *emails = emailArray;

   if (text.length > 0) {
        NSPredicate *filterPredictate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@",text];
        months = [emailArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredictate];
   }


    cell.emailLabel.text = emails[indexPath.row];
}


 - (NSInteger)autoSuggestionField:(UITextField *)field tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section forText:(NSString *)text {

    if (text.length == 0) {
        return emailArray.count;
    }

    NSPredicate *filterPredictate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", text];
     NSInteger count = [emailArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredictate].count;
    return count;

}


- (CGFloat)autoSuggestionField:(UITextField *)field tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forText:(NSString *)text {
    return 65;
}


- (void)autoSuggestionField:(UITextField *)field tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forText:(NSString *)text {
    // NSLog(@"Selected suggestion at index row - %ld", (long)indexPath.row);

    NSArray *emails = emailArray;

    if (text.length > 0) {
        NSPredicate *filterPredictate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", text];
        months = [emailArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredictate];
    }

   self.emailLabel.text =  emails[indexPath.row];

}
```

Comment: it is nice, simply coming suggestions below textfield now

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, use UItextField action for this.

**add this line in viewDidLoad**

```
txtSearch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldValueChanged(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
```

you will get resut in this funcation every time when textfield value changed

```
@objc func textFieldValueChanged(_ textField: UITextField)
{
    print(textField.text ?? "")
    //call your api here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in some tricky ways, one i use often is like below

Add editing change event to your text field as it'll tell you that text is changed

```
[_txtField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];


- (void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *) textField {
    if ([textField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]].length>0) {
        // make you api call
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

well to display your results you can use a table view. or something like [SearchTextField](https://github.com/apasccon/SearchTextField) or [MLPAutoCompleteTextField](https://github.com/EddyBorja/MLPAutoCompleteTextField)